# "No system tray detected" major problems after update

Tags: 12.04, launcher, compiz, system-tray

I converted a friend to ubuntu 12.04 a few years back, the computer has never had any issues that I know of and has always been kept up to date. Today's update has definitely broken some things. There is a "No system tray detected on this system" message and once logged in only the background image is displayed. No launcher, no desktop icons, no panels at all.

I also did get a compiz failure one time during all of this, and bug report notice, with a prompt to restart compiz, but nothing changed.

Ctrl-alt-t won't pull up a terminal so I used ctrl-alt-f2 to get to a command line - everything is up to date.

Some searching and reading suggested that missing dependencies and something to do with hplip could be an issue, but python-gobject and gobject2 are installed as well as python-appindicator, hplip wasn't installed so I installed it and rebboted, but nothing has changed... Any ideas for how to fix this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I manually made the jump to 14.04 with the hope that might fix something - but the problems persisted. I noticed during the update that there were some errors and forced installs around the nvidia 304 drivers so afterward I yanked the card and everything seems to run fine on the intel integrated graphics.

So it seems this was all a graphics driver problem...big surprise...all of my linux problems have somehow strangely been graphics card related in one way or another, so if you have a similar issue (or any issues) look there first. In my experience Nvidia's drivers have even broken some things that seem completely unrelated to the gpu at all - like wifi. Hopefully AMD's opensource efforts will pay off and there will be some decent GPU options in the future.